# Can someone recommend a terse solution to this problem in C#?

Tags: c#

How do I avoid code like this?

```
dblCalcTotal = dblCalcTotal + Utils.GetDecimal(txtJan.Text, 0);
dblCalcTotal = dblCalcTotal + Utils.GetDecimal(txtMar.Text, 0);
dblCalcTotal = dblCalcTotal + Utils.GetDecimal(txtApr.Text, 0);
dblCalcTotal = dblCalcTotal + Utils.GetDecimal(txtFeb.Text, 0);
dblCalcTotal = dblCalcTotal + Utils.GetDecimal(txtMay.Text, 0);
dblCalcTotal = dblCalcTotal + Utils.GetDecimal(txtJun.Text, 0);
dblCalcTotal = dblCalcTotal + Utils.GetDecimal(txtJul.Text, 0);
dblCalcTotal = dblCalcTotal + Utils.GetDecimal(txtAug.Text, 0);
dblCalcTotal = dblCalcTotal + Utils.GetDecimal(txtSep.Text, 0);
dblCalcTotal = dblCalcTotal + Utils.GetDecimal(txtOct.Text, 0);
dblCalcTotal = dblCalcTotal + Utils.GetDecimal(txtNov.Text, 0);
dblCalcTotal = dblCalcTotal + Utils.GetDecimal(txtDec.Text, 0);
```

Comment: Is this winforms or webforms?

Comment: Don't use Hungarian Notation.

Comment: @SLaks Don't use USELESS hungarian notation, see: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming they're in some sort of parent control...

```
for(var control in ParentControl.Controls){
  dblCalcTotal += Utils.GetDecimal(control.Text, 0);
}
```

Comment: And assuming that there are no other controls in the parent, which is unlikely.

Comment: Really? You never group your controls? If I had a group of "month" controls, I'd put them in a container...

Answer (score 2):

A simple loop would do it:

```
var items = new[] {txtJan, txtFeb, txtMar...};
dblCalcTotal = 0;
foreach(var item in items) {
    dblCalcTotal += Utils.GetDecimal(item.Text, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have this many controls, you should start thinking about a better control, one that show more than one value.  DataGridView is the best choice here since it allows editing.  This also gives a great opportunity to automatically make your UI work in any language.  Drop a DGV on your form, make the constructor look like this:

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Dim col = DataGridView1.Columns.Add("sales", "Sales")
    DataGridView1.Columns(col).ValueType = GetType(Decimal)
    DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    DataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
    DataGridView1.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders

    With System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(.Calendar.GetMonthsInYear(DateTime.Now.Year))
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            row.HeaderCell.Value = .DateTimeFormat.MonthNames(row.Index)
            row.Cells(col).Value = 0
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Now calculating the total becomes simple:

```
Private Sub ButtonTotalSales_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonTotalSales.Click
    Dim sales As Decimal = 0
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        sales += CDec(row.Cells("sales").Value)
    Next
    '' etc..
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

How's this?

```
double dblCalcTotal = Sum(txtJan.Text, txtFeb.Text, txtMar.Text .....);

private static double Sum(params string[] list)
{
    double result = 0;
    foreach (string s in list)
    {
        result += Utils.GetDecimal(s, 0);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your textboxes into a `List<TextBox>`.

You can then use LINQ:

```
calcTotal += monthBoxes.Sum(t => Utils.GetDecimal(t.Text, 0));
```

Comment: MonthBoxwes could maybe a LINQ query as well? (not sure if controlcollection supports that)

Comment: @Stefan: You could write `someParent.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(c => ???)`.

Answer (score 0):

First, add your textboxes to a List:

```
List<TextBox> months = new List<TextBox>();
months.add(txtJan);
months.add(txtFeb);
...
```

Then, inside your method:

```
foreach (Textbox month in months)
{
     dblCalcTotal += Utils.GetDecimal(month.Text, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you make the month boxes a control array?

If so, the code shortens to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < txtMonths.Length; i++)
    dblCalcTotal += Utils.GetDecimal(txtMonth[i].Text, 0);
```